# Adjusting image to row height in Xamarin ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to implement the ListView customization example (as seen [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/) in the Xamarin documentation).

In my example, in `<Image Source="{Binding image}" />`, my image is way bigger than the row height. I would like to adjust it to my row height.

I don't seem to find the correct keywords to find how to do it. I've tried modifying `Aspect`, `VerticalOptions`, `HorizontalOptions` (as options in `Image`)... nothing seems to stop the image from showing full size.

---

Also: this arose more questions for me, regarding the proper strategy of "how to fit an image in a row". I've read that rows have a fixed height and it is advised against to modify it, but resizing images is something to avoid, so IMO the image size would need to be the one limiting the row height. Also: I don't know if row heights are equal throughout all platforms (Android, iOS) and their different versions. With all these variables, what is the usual strategy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to set the HasUnevenRows property of the ListView?

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows/

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True"/>
```

Comment: That was the correct hint I needed. In my case, adding `<ListView HasUnevenRows="True"/>` + `<Image Source="{Binding image}" HeightRequest="30.0" />` solved the issue. Thanks.